# How to add support for wireless networking WPA2-PSK [AES] on Windows

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa2-psk

I have the problem on one of my machines that it is not possible to select WPA2-PSK [AES] network. It is missing in the network encryption dropdown (please see a picture below from my computer where it shows (and works), on the other computer the currently selected alternative AES does not show)

Any pointers on how to get it added are much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your NIC (hardware, possibly driver) may not support WPA2.  What brand and model?

Comment: IBM T41, more than a couple of years old by now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, you need either a newer network card, or a newer driver.

Forget the brand of device you bought and just take a look in device manager for the actual chipset maker - [Atheros](http://www.atheros.com/), [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw), [Intel](http://www.intel.com) etc.

Go to the site and see if there is an updated driver you can use.

If an update does not work, it means that WPA2-PSK is simply not compatible with your current card and you will have to buy another.

Comment: I think WPA2 support comes from the OS, not the network card driver.

Comment: Maybe, not 100% sure if there is a minimum OS requirement, but what I said certainly does count. I get jobs like this all the time where a new laptop does not support WPA2-PSK and all it takes is a driver update and suddenly the option appears.

Comment: Thanks for help. Have updated the drivers and unfortunately no WPA2-psk option appeared. I am not really comfortable with a lower encryption level like WEP so I will keep that machine on the LAN.

Answer (score 3):

Update for Windows XP (KB893357) 
This update to Windows XP provides support for Wi-Fi Protected Access 2 (WPA2), which is the latest standards-based wireless security solution derived from the IEEE 802.11i standard.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have (at least) Service Pack 2 installed.  If you can't install it for some reason, there's a [hotfix](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=662BB74D-E7C1-48D6-95EE-1459234F4483&displaylang=en).

Comment: Shouldn't it be Service Pack 3? (IIRC, you need either SP2+hotfix or SP3)

Comment: I have SP3 loaded and the option is not available.